# error: ‘SkipEmptyParts’ is not a member of ‘Qt’

Tags: qt, qt5

I am randomly encountering this error without updating the code using `qt5`:

> error: ‘SkipEmptyParts’ is not a member of ‘Qt’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved replacing `Qt::SkipEmptyParts` with `QString::SkipEmptyParts` because `Qt::SkipEmptyParts` has been deprecated.

If you would like to keep the back-compatibility but also use the new version for qt versions >= 5.11.x you could use:

```cpp
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 11, 0)
  const auto skip_empty_parts = Qt::SkipEmptyParts;
#else
  const auto skip_empty_parts = QString::SkipEmptyParts;
#endif
```

**UPDATED:**
as @Alienpenguin said, `QString::SkipEmptyParts` has been deprecated and removed in Qt6, it is possible to use `Qt::SkipEmptyParts` now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Qt::SkipEmptyParts` is the correct way to use it (since Qt 5.14)

see: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring-obsolete.html#SplitBehavior-enum
and: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#SplitBehaviorFlags-enum

`QString::SkipEmptyParts` has been deprecated long ago and removed in Qt6.

Since  Qt 5.14 `Qt::SkipEmptyParts` was introduced and is the preferred way to use it; up to latest Qt 6.X